# List the four steps that are necessary to run a program on a completely dedicated machine—a computer that is running only that program

Tags: operating-system

In my OS class, we use a text book "Operating System Concepts" by Silberschatz.
I ran into this question and answer in practice exercise and wanted to know further explanation.

```
Q. List the four steps that are necessary to run a program on a completely dedicated machine—a computer that is running only that program.

A. 
1. Reserve machine time
2. Manually load program into memory
3. Load starting address and begin execution
4. Monitor and control execution of program from console
```

Actually, I don't understand the first step, "Reserve machine time". Could you explain what each step means here? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should ask your school to upgrade your course materials to something newer than the 1980s.

Comment: 1980s, @KenWhite? It sounds more like the 1960s!

Comment: Operating System Concepts is a modern book (the latest edition came out last year), it's just that the first edition was published in 1985 and the author has chosen to keep the old stuff in it. However, the bigger problem with the book is, in my opinion, that it is excessively verbose. Principles of Modern Operating Systems seems to do a better job in this regard, although I can't vouch for its contents as I haven't read it (but I'd be surprised if it was different in any significant way).

Comment: Thank you so much. It is very old materials... Thanks for all suggestions and answers! It helps me a lot

Answer (score 3):

If the computer can run only a single program, but the computer is shared between multiple people, then you will have to agree on a time that you get to use the computer to run your program.  This was common up through the 1960s.  It is still common in some contexts, such as very expensive super-computers.  Time-sharing became popular during the 1970s, enabling multiple people to appear to share a computer at the same time, when in fact the computer quickly switched from one person's program to another.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion teaching about old batch systems in today's OS classes is not very helpful. You should use some text which is more relevant to contemporary OS design such as the [Minix Book](https://mcdtu.files.wordpress.com/2017/03/tanenbaum_woodhull_operating-systems-design-implementation-3rd-edition.pdf)

Apart from that if you really want to learn about old systems then [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing) has pretty good explanation.

> Early computers were capable of running only one program at a time.
>   Each user had sole control of the machine for a scheduled period of
>   time. They would arrive at the computer with program and data, often
>   on punched paper cards and magnetic or paper tape, and would load
>   their program, run and debug it, and carry off their output when done